# VBA Excel make array of sequential numbers

Tags: matlab, vba, excel

I am working in VBA for Excel at the moment but am really only versed in Matlab. It's important for my work to stay in the memory of vba (not on the worksheets of excel) for time purposes.
What I need to do is make an array of sequential integers, say 4000 through 5000.
In matlab this is really easy, I would just do... i = 4000:5000, or i=4000:1:5000. With the 1 in the second case being my 'step.'
I was wondering what is the best way to achieve this result in vba?
Thanks

Comment: Also I'm aware of a way to do it using a for loop, something like:

For i = 1 To MaxDate - MinDate + 1
   aDate(i) = MinDate + i - 1
Next i

But there's got to be a simpler way like the matlab version.

Comment: What do you want to do? (you might just need a loop and not an array)

Comment: I think you'll need a for-loop

Comment: The array will be a list of excel converted dates that I will use to compare vs arrays of start dates and end dates

Comment: *But there's got to be a simpler way*.  **Nope**.

Comment: If you want an array of integers from 4000 to 5000: `v = Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(4000:5000))")`. Of course you're probably still going to have to loop when comparing them to your list.

Comment: Are these 'converted dates' incremented by 1 day, by any chance?

Comment: Thanks Rory, I think that'll work for me.

Comment: @Rory Should I be surprised that the resulting type is `Double`?

Comment: @Alan Not really - Double is Excel's default number type.

Comment: @Rory Well, OK ... but for row numbers?  Anyway, can I assign this to a variable so that the variable type is an array of `Double` (instead of `Variant`)?

Comment: @Alan only with a loop in which case you may as well do that instead.

Comment: @Rory Thanks.  As a newbie, I'm finding this to be a very odd language, and this adds two oddities.

Answer (score 4):

Without looping - Just seen Rory's same answer above after posting

```
Sub MakeArray()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, arr As Variant
    x = 4000: y = 5000
    arr = Evaluate("Row(" & x & ":" & y & ")")

    'Show result
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(y - x + 1) = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: this would be improved with `First` and `Last`, instead of `x` and `y`. x and y are standard identifiers for the two axis of a 2D space, so it's harder to understand your code at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example of creating and then displaying a set of sequential numbers:

```
Sub seqnum()
    Dim firstnum As Long, secnum As Long
    firstnum = 7
    secnum = 23
    ReDim ary(1 To secnum - firstnum + 1) As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(ary)
        ary(i) = firstnum + (i - 1)
    Next i


    msg = ""
    For i = 1 To UBound(ary)
        msg = msg & i & vbTab & ary(i) & vbCrLf
    Next i
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I Us "Fill"  - "Series":
Write in first cell number ex. 400 and in the "Series" window insert increment step and in "Stop Value" last value. ex. 420
Or with Macro

```
Range("I1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4000"
Range("I1").Select
Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
    Step:=1, Stop:=4020, Trend:=False
```

Comment: From OP: *It's important for my work to stay in the memory of vba (not on the worksheets of excel)*

Comment: all macro´s You make save and reuse in another Project.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but the point of *my* comment is that your solution is *using a Worksheet* as an intermediary for transforming data. The question *explicitly* asks to avoid these methods.  Cheers.

Comment: VBA for Excel, and Macro is almost the same

Comment: I *do* understand that macros are recorded in Excel, and represented by the VBA language construct, however, your answer is not satisfactory because it uses a method that the OP explicitly rejects.