# Getting the maximum value of a specific column in a 2d array

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, max

In continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63937508/aggregating-part-of-a-2d-array-in-a-column-in-said-array) I now need the maximum value contained within one column of the array.

I have a 2d array, with flexible dimensions:

```
arr_emissions(0 to n, 0 to m)
```

Where `n` is 22 or larger (but no larger then around 400), and `m` is 6 or larger.

In the smallest case column `m = 6` contains the sum of columns `m = 2 - 5`. I now need the maximum value of this column.

For 1d arrays there are plenty of examples of the usage of `application.worksheetfunction.max`. So I thought to combine that with `application.worksheetfunction.index()` as I did last time, but in this case the row number is a required argument, whilst I want the maximum value within a column, so from every row.

I tried `wks_AI_res.Cells(row, 11).Value = Application.Max(Application.Index(arr_emissions, 0, emissions_rows))` which yields me the #VALUE error. In this the value of `emissions_rows` = 6.

As the dimensions of the array are flexible I would like to implement a robust method, that preferly doesn't loop over the entire array.

Comment: the row is required but `0` will return the whole column.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for the tip. In my case the array is 0-based, and I get the #Value error returned.

Comment: Then create a function that will return a 1D array of the given column of a provided 2d array.

Comment: @ScottCraner solved it by creating a 1D array that contains the row numbers of 1 till max, and enter that as row requirement in the `MAX()` function